# This giving me a same result!!!!!! FOR ALL 3 Why? What is wrong here?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
while shopping:
    user_input = input(
        f'What area do you want to explore?: \n a) Food \n b) Fruit \n c) Dairy \n:').upper
    if user_input == 'A' or 'FOOD':
        print(food_list)
        break

    elif user_input == 'B' or 'FRUIT':
        print(fruit_list)
        break

    elif user_input == 'C' or 'DAIRY':
        print(dairy_list)
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if user_input == 'A' or 'FOOD'
```

Is always `True` so , Change all if statements like this :

```
if user_input == 'A' or user_input = 'FOOD'
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before"

Comment: In particular, this is so much a FAQ we have a language-agnostic duplicate target for it, since there were so many duplicates in each of the Python, JavaScript, and other per-language tags.

Comment: Thank you, so much you solved my problem.☺️